# Handle tap event for ListBoxItem template from code in Windows phone

Tags: c#, xaml, listbox, windows-phone, listboxitem

I am using Panorama Control in Windows Phone. In Panorama control I am dynamically adding Panorama Items from code. In PanoramaItem I have setup ListBox. I am setting up ItemTemplate for ListBox from code. Here is the code where I am setting up ItemTemplate.

```
private void AddContentInPanoramaItem(PanoramaItem panoramaItem)
{           
    ListBox listBox = new ListBox();
    DataTemplate itemTmp = (DataTemplate)XamlReader.Load(
                                                    @"<DataTemplate xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007"">
                                                    <Grid Background=""Green"" Width=""400"" Margin=""0 10 0 10"">
                                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                            <RowDefinition/>
                                                            <RowDefinition/>
                                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width=""Auto""/>
                                                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                        <Border Background=""White"" Margin=""5 0 5 0"" Width=""60"" Height=""100"" Grid.RowSpan=""2"" CornerRadius=""1"">            
                                                            <Image Source=""Assets\phoneImage.png"" />
                                                         </Border>
                                                        <TextBlock Text=""{Binding Name}"" FontSize=""35"" Grid.Column=""1"" />
                                                        <TextBlock Text=""{Binding Number}"" FontSize=""20"" Grid.Column=""1"" Grid.Row=""2"" />
                                                    </Grid>
                                                </DataTemplate>");
    listBox.ItemTemplate = itemTmp;
    var contacts = from contact in m_contactList
                    where contact.Category == panoramaItem.Header.ToString()
                    orderby contact.Name
                    select contact;
    listBox.ItemsSource = contacts;
    panoramaItem.Content = listBox;             
}
```

Now I want to add tap event for . I defined a method to handle tap event.

```
private void Border_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{}
```

But When I add Tap=""Border_Tap""  in  tag my app gets crashed. Exception says "Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component."

Any idea on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer you can't do that :

> XAML for Load should not attempt to specify x:Class, or include any XAML-defined attributes for event handlers. Load logic cannot integrate the loaded XAML with code-behind classes at runtime. If you want to add event handlers, you must do so in code by referencing objects obtained from within the object tree structure of the Load result, and using language-specific syntax for attaching handlers (such as +=). For more information on attaching events using code, see Events Overview for Silverlight. [[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189076%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)]

And I can't see any simple workaround for this limitation so far. If possible, just define the `<DataTemplate>` in XAML, put it in page's Resources for example, then you can use it from code :

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007" x:Key="listBoxItemTemplate">
        <Grid Background="Green" Width="400" Margin="0 10 0 10">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Border Tap="Border_Tap" Background="White" Margin="5 0 5 0" Width="60" Height="100" Grid.RowSpan="2" CornerRadius="1">
                <Image Source="Assets\phoneImage.png" />
            </Border>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="35" Grid.Column="1" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number}" FontSize="20" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
//in C# code
........
listBox.ItemTemplate = (DataTemplate)this.Resources["listBoxItemTemplate"];
........
```